# alasql requires xlsx which is already included

Tags: excel, xlsx, alasql, js-xlsx

I am trying to export data to an excel sheet using `alasql` and `xlsx`. I have followed all the guidelines here: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Xlsx

This is my function:

```
exportToExcel(data: any) {
   console.log(XLSX.version);

   alasql
     .promise('SELECT * INTO XLSX("test.csv",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [data])
     .then(function (data) { console.log(data); })
     .catch(function (err) { console.log('Error:', err); });;
}
```

which gives me this error in my console together with the `XLSX` version:

`VM9931 main.bundle.js:1044 0.12.4
 VM9931 main.bundle.js:1047 Error: Error: Please include the xlsx.js library
    at B (VM9930 vendor.bundle.js:6298)
    at Object.A.into.XLSX (VM9930 vendor.bundle.js:6303)`

The problem I am experiencing is that I have already included the `XLSX` library and it's working correctly (the version logged is `0.12.4`). If I change the `XLSX("test.csv")...` to `CSV("test.csv")...` it exports to CSV perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading source code from `alasql`, I looked closely on the part which get `XLSX` :

```js
var getXLSX = function() {
var XLSX = alasql["private"].externalXlsxLib;

  if (XLSX) {
    return XLSX;
  }

  if (utils.isNode || utils.isBrowserify || utils.isMeteorServer) {
    /*not-for-browser/*
    XLSX = require('xlsx') || null;
    //*/
  } else {
    XLSX = utils.global.XLSX || null;
  }

  if (null === XLSX) {
    throw new Error('Please include the xlsx.js library');
  }

  return XLSX;

};
```

I don't know exactly why but line `XLSX = require('xlsx') || null` is commented so you need to explicitly set `externalXlsxLib` to use `xlsx` :

```js
import * as alasql from 'alasql';
alasql["private"].externalXlsxLib = require('xlsx');
```

### Update

As suggested in comment there is now a setter function that you can use to provide `xlsx`. You should definitely use this cleaner approach.

```js
import * as alasql from 'alasql';
var XLSX = require('xlsx')
alasql.setXLSX(XLSX);
```

Comment: You should probably prefer using the existing setter `alasql.setXLSX(XLSX)`

Comment: It has been long since I was looking into this. Based on your explanation, I think you are probably right. I will set your answer as correct until/unless someone comes up with some good points why not.