# Angular 5 with Cli alasql can't find xlsx.js

Tags: angular, include, command-line-interface, xlsx, alasql

xlsx from JSON with alasql and xlsx. I was able to generate a xls with alasql, but the xlsx generation fails. I added the script to the cli and the compiler has no errors.

When I call the function genXlsx(), which does the rendering, I get a console-error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8TCh.png)

StatsComponent.ts

```
import * as alasql from 'alasql';

export class StatsComponent {
  genXlsx(): void {   
    const data1 = [{ a: 1, b: 10 }, { a: 2, b: 20 }];
    const data2 = [{ a: 100, b: 10 }, { a: 200, b: 20 }];
    const opts = [{ sheetid: 'Good', header: true }, { sheetid: 'Two', header: false }];
    const res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("MyAwesomeData.xlsx",?) FROM ?', [opts, [data1, data2]]);
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "alasql": "^0.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.8",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "responsive-directives-angular2": "^0.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.58",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
```

.angular-cli.json

```
 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js",
    "../node_modules/alasql/dist/alasql.min.js"
  ],
```

Can someone help me with this? thanks :)

Comment: try to include the library in the typings.js file https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: thanks but didn't work

Comment: Try the response in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132971/alasql-requires-xlsx-which-is-already-included